# Adding receiver and service to an android reminder app

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm creating an android reminder application using AlarmManager. My main activity's GUI contains a time and datepicker dialog and a button that calls setReminder function which fetches time and date that user enters and sets reminder for that particular date and time . When the reminder time occurs it moves to another activity whose GUI contains buttons for snooze and cancel. I played the alarm using MediaPlayer. Both buttons are working well. I want my alarm to run in the background even if the application is closed and want my app to notify the OS about the alarm. That is why I want to add broadcast receiver and service to this application. How can I do that?

Main Activity code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;


   private Calendar calendar;
   private TextView dateView;
   private int year, month, day;
   private int hour,min;
  // private int sYear, sMonth, sDay;
   //private int sHour,sMin;


   private EditText time;
   private String format = "";
   PendingIntent pi;




 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(year, month+1, day);


      time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
      calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

      hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      showTime(hour, min);       


}
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public void setDate(View view) {
   showDialog(999);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ca", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
   .show();
   }
  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (id == 999) {
      return new DatePickerDialog(this,myDateListener, year, month, day);
   }
   else if (id == 1111) {
       return new TimePickerDialog(this,myTimeListener, hour,min,true);
    }
   return null;
  }

 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
   }
   };

  private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
   dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
   .append(month).append("/").append(year));
   this.year=year;
   this.month=(month-1);
   this.day=day; 

 }


 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public void setTime(View view) {
 showDialog(1111);
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
 .show();
 }


private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener myTimeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    showTime(arg1,arg2);

}

};
public void showTime(int hour, int min) {

   time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(" : ").append(min)
      .append(" ").append(format));

      this.hour= hour;
      this.min= min;
   }  


    public void setAlarm(View v) 
   { 



   alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Alarm.class);

    PendingIntent                pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);


    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day); 

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
  long timeToAlarm = calendar.getTimeInMillis();



  alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi); 



}


     @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Main xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="setAlarm"
    android:text="Set" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
    android:onClick="setDate"
    android:text="Set Date" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:ems="10" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:onClick="setTime"
    android:text="SetTime" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="Set Hobby"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Alarm.java

```
 public class Alarm extends Activity {
   MediaPlayer mp;
   AlarmManager AlmMgr;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tum);
    mp.start();
  }
public void onCancel(View v)
{
 mp.stop();
 mp=null;
 }

 public void onSnooze(View v)
 {
  mp.stop();
  AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

  calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); 
  long snoozeTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

  Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
  AlarmIntent.putExtra("REQUEST CODE", 1);


  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, AlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);   
  AlmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, snoozeTime, pi);

 }




 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_alarm, menu);
    return true;
 }

}
```

activity_alarm_xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".Alarm" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
    android:onClick="onCancel"
    android:text="Cancel" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:text="Snooze"
    android:onClick="onSnooze" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add broadcast receiver and service in this application. How can I do that?

Well, it will be impossible  to help unless you tell us what the purpose of both, what you want to do with them, and what you already tried.

Add class of **BradcastReceiver**:

```
public class MySnoozeReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm .class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Don't forget the manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name='.MySnoozeReciever'>
    </receiver>
```

Modify those lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MySnoozeReciever.class);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);
```

Comment: I just created a single reminder application that fetches date and time entered by the user and plays alarm at that time. The user enters date and time and clicks Set Reminder button. The setReminder function is called and it passes the intent to another activity(Alarm.java) at the time entered by user. In Alarm.java  I used MediaPlayer that plays the alarm. I also used snooze and cancel buttons in this activity. All these are working well. I want  my alarm to run in the background even if the application is closed and want my app to notify the OS about the alarm.

Comment: Please edit your question, with the additional explanations. Don't repeat on what you already wrote